# How to show products on homepage by category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, products

I am trying to show products on the Homepage by category.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="158125" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I have tried this but did not work. 
Note: I am using the Porto theme. If you can please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Magento admin panel
Content -> Pages -> Choose your home page

- Click the Insert Widget button
- [image]
- Then choose Catalog Product List
- Choose condition as category and its ID

Save page and Clear the Magento cache
then you will see the products in the category

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/194086)

Comment: Sorry updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much